# How to include a selection screen into another screen

Tags: abap, dynpro, sap-selection-screens

I need to include a selection screen of a given program (`ZPRG1`) into another program's (`ZPRG2`) subscreen (`100`).

When I run the program `ZPRG2` below, before any screen is displayed, there is the runtime error `DYNP_WRONG_SCREEN_TYPE` (Wrong screen type: The screen has either been defined incorrectly or is being used incorrectly).

**ZPRG1** (selection screen 1000 with one field `TEST`):

```
REPORT zprg1. 
PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
```

**ZPRG2**:

```
REPORT zprg2.
CALL SCREEN 100.
MODULE pai INPUT.
  SET SCREEN 0. " close screen (all the time)
ENDMODULE.
```

**Screen 100**: (of ZPRG2)
The screen layout defines the subscreen area `SUBAREA`, and any number of elements, and the flow logic is as follows:

```
PROCESS BEFORE OUTPUT.
  CALL SUBSCREEN subarea INCLUDING 'ZPRG1' '1000'.
PROCESS AFTER INPUT.
  CALL SUBSCREEN subarea.
  MODULE pai.
```

How to prevent the runtime error?

Comment: A selection screen works like any other screen. Is your question "how to make a selection screen be defined as a subscreen", or "how to include a subscreen into a subscreen area" or both questions?

Comment: Hi Sandra,  Please let me know how to make selection screen as subscreen?

Comment: I have reworded the question so that it conforms more stackoverflow principles (especially adding a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). Please confirm whether it fits your question, or edit it. Thx.

Comment: Hi Sandra, this question suits my requirement. I am getting the same runtime error :(

Answer (score 3):

In the dynpro technology, to include a screen "A" into a screen "B", the screen "A" must be defined as a **subscreen** and the screen "B" must define a "subscreen area" to contain the screen "A". The [flow logic](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abendynpro_flow_logic_glosry.htm) of the screen "B" must contain the statement [**`CALL SUBSCREEN <subscreen_area> INCLUDING ...`**](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=dynpcall.htm), which refers to the subscreen number to include either statically or via a global variable.

As with a normal screen, a **selection screen** can also be defined as a subscreen by defining it as a "standalone selection screen" (wrapping its elements inside the ABAP statements [`SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN <any-screen-number>`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselection-screen_normal.htm) and `SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN <any-screen-number>`), and adding the words **"AS SUBSCREEN"** after `BEGIN OF SCREEN <any-screen-number>`). For example:

```
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1001 AS SUBSCREEN.
    PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1001.
```

If you have to include an existing selection screen, which is not yet defined as a subscreen, there are two main possibilities:

1. If it was already defined as a "standalone screen" (with `SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN ...`), and it's to be used only as a subscreen, you may simply add `AS SUBSCREEN` as said above.
2. If it has to be used both as a subscreen and as a normal screen, then the most simple solution is to wrap its elements inside a block (ABAP statements [`SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK <block ID>`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselection-screen_block.htm) and `SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK <block ID>`), and define another selection screen which includes this block (ABAP statement [`SELECTION-SCREEN INCLUDE BLOCKS <block ID>`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapselection-screen_include.htm)).

Below are two examples for the case 2.

**Example 1, with the default selection screen** (1000 cf footnote)

- Before:

```
REPORT zprg1.

PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX. " screen 1000 cf footnote
```

- After:

```
REPORT zprg1.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b1000.
    PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1000.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1001 AS SUBSCREEN.
    SELECTION-SCREEN INCLUDE BLOCKS b1000.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1002.
```

**Example 2 with a Standalone selection screen** (1002, included using `CALL SUBSCREEN subarea INCLUDING 'ZPRG1' '1002'.`)

- Before:

```
REPORT zprg1.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1002.
    PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1002.
```

- After:

```
REPORT zprg1.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1002.
SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF BLOCK b1002.
    PARAMETERS test AS CHECKBOX.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF BLOCK b1002.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1002.

SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1003 AS SUBSCREEN.
    SELECTION-SCREEN INCLUDE BLOCKS b1002.
SELECTION-SCREEN END OF SCREEN 1003.
```

Footnote:

(1) The selection screen parameters which are not placed inside `SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN ... END OF SCREEN ...` are implicitly part of the "default selection screen" (`1000`). Note that using `SELECTION-SCREEN BEGIN OF SCREEN 1000...` leads to a syntax error.